# how to add one-row columns into empty dataframe in r

Tags: r

I have a tryCatch block that returns a dataframe. In some cases, it returns a empty dataframe with 0 rows. No matter it's empty or not, I need to add some data in there. (some columns with one row). I found when it returns an empty dataframe, adding columns to the dataframe always give me error. For example:

```
dt <- data.frame()
for (a in  0:2) {
    table <- tryCatch(
                { mtcars %>%
                    filter(am==a) %>% 
                    group_by(vs) %>% 
                    summarise(n=n()) %>% 
                    spread(vs, n)
                },
                error = function(e) {
                    return(NULL)
                } )

    table$am = a 
    dt <- bind_rows(dt, table)
}
```

Here is the error message:

```
 Error in `$<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, "am", value = 2L) : replacement has 1 row, data has 0
```

Anyone can help solving this issue? Thanks a lot.

Comment: Show the `tryCatch` block. Or better yet entire code block so we can see context.

Answer (score 1):

One option could be to declare your `data.frame` with valid columns but `0` rows. This provides flexibility to `add row` using `nrow(data)+1` and assigned values of desired columns.

```
data = data.frame(ID = integer(), Result = integer())

data[nrow(data)+1,] = c(1, 5)
data
# ID Result
# 1  1      5
```

**EDIT**

OP is facing problem with the `tryCatch` block. It seems there are conditions when exception is thrown from `tryCatch` block and value of `table` is assigned as `NULL` in such cases.

The possible fix can be to replace

```
table$am = a 
dt <- bind_rows(dt, table)
```

lines with

```
  if(!is.null(table)){
    table$am = a 
    dt <- bind_rows(dt, table)
  }else{
    dt[nrow(dt)+1, "am"] <- a
  }
```

Comment: I think I did not make my question clear. I added the trycatch block. Thanks.@MKR

Comment: @zesla your code works fine for me. The value of `dt` is  `   0  1 am
1 12  7  0
2  6  7  1
3 NA NA  2`

Comment: @zesla `dplyr::bind_rows(dt, table)` works just fine for me.

Comment: weird. It did not work for me. If I change it to (a in 0:1), it works. I think because am=2 is not in mtcars dataset. Are you sure the code works? @WKR

Comment: @zesla yes. It worked for me. Actually with `am=2` there is an error from `spread` which causing the problem. Let me think of a fix for it. Actually `am` doesnt have value of `2`. Hence `summarise` doesnt get any row and finally `gather` returns an exception.

Comment: I purposely add am=2 in there, just to illustrate the issue in my work. Also, I do need a row with am=2 (rest of them NAs).  The code that works for you is the same I posted? @MKR

Comment: @zesla You should protect your code against value of `table` being `NULL` in case there is exception. I'll modify the suggested edit which can work for you.

Comment: I do need the row with am=2, rest of them NAs.  My actual work is more complicated than this. Some other columns with be added for those rows with NAs. How can I keep those rows when am=2? Thanks! @MKR

Comment: @zesla No problem. You can just add `else` block and add whatever you want to add for cases exception occurred. But best solution will be write a function and use `apply/lapply` functions to perform this operation. Because there is good possibility to get results with different rows. Hence final results in `list` will be good options.

Answer (score 0):

```
data<-data.frame(rbind(data, ID=1))
```

Comment: thanks. But if the data is not empty, your solution will give error. @doviod

Comment: so precede it with `if(dim(data)[2]==0)`

Comment: I think I did not make my question clear. I added the trycatch block. Thanks. @doviod

Answer (score 0):

You can't add entries to an empty data.frame like that. Try
`data = data.frame("ID"=1,"Result"=5)`